# The entity type RelyingParty is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection

I am getting the error  **The entity type RelyingParty is not part of the model for the current context even though it exists**.

My edmx name is **SSO**. The edmx is present within **Entities** folder in **Entrada.DAL** assembly. Following is the code of SSO.Context class

```
namespace Entrada.DAL.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class SSOEntities : DbContext
    {
        public SSOEntities()
            : base("name=SSOEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<KeyValuePair> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RelyingParty> RelyingParties { get; set; }
    }
```

Following is the connections string in web.config

```
<add name="SSOEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.SSO.csdl|res://*/Entities.SSO.ssdl|res://*/Entities.SSO.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=dbname;initial catalog=SSO;persist security info=True;user id=user;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is the code where the error is thrown:

```
public List<RelyingPartyDALDTO> GetAllRelyingParty()
        {
            List<RelyingParty> relyingPartDB = DBContext.RelyingParties.ToList();
            List<RelyingPartyDALDTO> relyingPartyList = RelyingPartyEntityToDAL.Map<List<RelyingPartyDALDTO>>(relyingPartDB);
            return relyingPartyList;
        }
```

DBContext is:

```
public SSOEntities DBContext
        {
            get
            {
                if (SSOEntities == null)
                {
                    SSOEntities = new SSOEntities();
                }
                return SSOEntities;
            }

        }
```

I am getting error on executing the statement:
List relyingPartDB = DBContext.RelyingParties.ToList();
[Check the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM6vi.png)

Can you see the error in DBContext? Already existing table(KeyValuePair) does not throw any error but the newly added table RelyingParty throws that error.

I am not understanding what is the problem. For any new table i add to edmx, i am facing this issue.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your SSOEntities class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RelyingParty>().ToTable("RelyingParty");
}
```

Comment: I tried that too as suggested in the previous queries about the same. it is not helping

Comment: i have added the code that is throwing the error in the query.